# etherpad-lite permission denied, open './SESSIONKEY.txt'

Tags: node.js, centos, etherpad, jitsi

using

- centos 7
- node v8.6.0
- npm v5.3.0

trying to setup etherpad on centos like described here: https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite#gnulinux-and-other-unix-like-systems

It should be used inside Jitsi-meet: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/wiki/Etherpad-addition-example

but getting the error: 
`node[9613]: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open './SESSIONKEY.txt'`

also tried to look for this file, but can't find it, do I have to somehow generate it first?
Seems to me something is missing in the installation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after I've gone through: https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-etherpad-on-a-centos-7-vps/

the SESSONKEY.txt was generated. I think the key was to run './bin/installDeps.sh'